# compute AUC metric for Matrix Factorization output

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, auc, matrix-factorization

Initial Matrix contains `1` for known links (`0` for unknown and missed entries) in a link prediction system. Outputs of Matrix Factorization are predicted values for missed entries to calculate `AUC`:

1. Hide `20%` of known links (set `20%` of entries with `1` to `0` in the matrix )
2. Sort output of Factorization and discard indexes used for train (`80%` of `1`)
3. Set `N` to number of hided values
4. Get `N` top predicted values and check if they are hided values (class label set to `1`) or not (class label set to `0`)
5. Compute `AUC` using `N` top predictions

I know `perfcurve` in matlab computes `AUC`, but I need to be sure about the above process to provide labelled data for `perfcurve`.

Any comment is really appreciated.

Comment: Which step are you struggling with?

Comment: I am not sure about choosing N top score from m*k factorized value.

Comment: I am not sure about choosing N top score from i.e 1 million factorized value. expecting that N top link be the same as hided values is reseanoble or not? (we may have 1 million entries with 4000 known '1' others set to '0' and #hided values=N=1000 )